# Why can't a protocol not be used as a type for a generic type in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift2

Can anyone explain me why this is not possible in plane swift:

```
protocol ProtocolA {
    func a()
}

class B<T: ProtocolA> {
}

class ClassC {
    func c(value: B<ProtocolA>) {

    }
}
```

This yields the following error: `error: protocol type 'ProtocolA' does not conform to protocol 'ProtocolA' because 'ProtocolA' is not declared @objc`. I can fix this by declaring the protocol as @objc but I want to understand why because this looks like a very essential use case of generics to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug in Swift 2 since this works in Swift 1.2

As workaround you can use a generic function instead:

```
class ClassC {
    func c<T: ProtocolA>(value: B<T>) {

    }
}
```

**Edit**

As of Xcode 7 beta 6 you get an error message:

> using 'ProtocolA' as a concrete type conforming to protocol
>   'ProtocolA' is not supported

So this should be considered normal behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Need to check if it is fixed in the latest version. Just came across another issue I don't really understand why it does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238469/how-can-i-use-a-protocol-with-a-typealias-as-a-func-parameter

Comment: @V1ru8 Now, as of Xcode 7 beta 6 you get an error message if you try to use your code: "using 'ProtocolA' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'ProtocolA' is not supported". But I haven't found any reason why. The second issue is that a `typealias` is not written as generic parameter in angle brackets but if you want to know why consider asking another question on stackoverflow.