# How can I use a protocol with a typealias as a func parameter?

Tags: swift, swift2

The following code:

```
protocol ProtocolA {
}

protocol ProtocolB {
    typealias T: ProtocolA
    var value : Array<T> { get set }
}

class ProtocolC {
    func method<T: ProtocolA>(value: ProtocolB<T>)
    {

    }
}
```

Yields these errors:

```
error: cannot specialize non-generic type 'ProtocolB'
func method<T: ProtocolA>(value: ProtocolB<T>)

error: generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature
func method<T: ProtocolA>(value: ProtocolB<T>)

error: protocol 'ProtocolB' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
func method<T: ProtocolA>(value: ProtocolB<T>)
```

Can anyone explain me why this is not possible? Is this a bug or intentional?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `method`?

Comment: Lets say I have different implementations of ProtocolA and ProtocolB for different hardware devices. Then method should perform some algorithm on it. Now I can't use subclassing since the concrete implementations already have to subclass another class that should not be exposed.

Comment: I can actually work around this, it is more that I'd like to understand why this is not possible since it looks like a valid use case of generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specialize generic *protocol* with `<>`.

Instead, you can:

```
func method<B: ProtocolB where B.T: ProtocolA>(value: B) {
}
```

That says, `method` accepts `B` where `B` conforms `ProtocolB` and *its `T`* conforms `ProtocolA`.

And, in this case, you don't need `where B.T: ProtocolA` because it's obvious.

```
func method<B: ProtocolB>(value: B) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<T>` after the `B` argument in the `method` definition. You don't need the `<T: ProtocolA>` in the method signature, either.

```
protocol ProtocolA {
}

typealias T = ProtocolA

protocol ProtocolB {
    var value : [T] { get set }
}

class ProtocolC {
    func method(value: ProtocolB)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: That does only solve two of these issues. The `error: protocol 'ProtocolB' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` still unsolved

Comment: That's more complicated. I *think* that it's because specifying a parameter of type `ProtocolB` isn't sufficient because the `typealias` somehow requires more information about the `ProtocolB` class. If you take out the `typealias` and just specify the body as `var value : Array<T> { get set }` (or, better yet, `var value: [T] { get set }`), then it compiles.

Comment: Can you post the full code? I don't get that to compile.